# Avoiding #Func! Error in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a field in Access that is formatted like this: Los Angeles, CA #00001

I need to modify the text field to look like this: #001 - Los Angeles, CA

To do this, I'm using this formula:

```
 "#" & Format([STORE NUMBER],"000") & " - " & Trim(Left([STORE NAME],InStr(1,[STORE NAME],"#")-1))
```

The problem I am running into is that not every record in my data set is formatted the same. There are a few instances where the location name is:
"Test Store for California".

If this is the case, I get a "#Func!" error, likely because there is no "#" sign to look for to apply the formula.

Can anyone assist in finding a workaround to avoid this error.

Ideally I would like it so that if the the ouput does result in a "#Func!" error, just to use the original name like so:

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
|        Original        |          New           |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| Los Angeles, CA #00001 | #001 - Los Angeles, CA |
| Test Store for CA      | Test Store for CA      |
| San Diego, CA #00002   | #002 - San Diego, CA   |
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append a `"#"` to the end of the string prior to searching for a `"#"` using `InStr`:

```
"#" & Format([STORE NUMBER],"000") & " - " & Trim(Left([STORE NAME],InStr(1,[STORE NAME]&"#","#")-1))
```

If a `"#"` already exists, the `InStr` will find the location of the existing one.  If one doesn't exist then `InStr(1,[STORE NAME]&"#","#")-1` will just return the length of `[STORE NAME]` and therefore the `Left` will just return the entire field.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could have a Function return the formatted value and if `#` does not exist, return the original value.

```
Public Function SplitStore(ByVal value_ As String) As String

    If InStr(1, value_, "#") = 0 Then
        SplitStore = value_
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(value_, "#")

    SplitStore = "#" & Format(arr(1), "000") & " -" & arr(0)
End Function
```

To call it:

```
SELECT SplitStore([STORE NUMBER]) As FormattedStore
...


'#001 -Los Angeles, CA
```